# Increase Spacing Between Lightning-Icon and title

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightningstylesheets

Trying to get the spacing between this icon and text.

Any advice?

```html
<h3 slot ="title" class="slds-card__header-title slds-media__body">
    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:channel_program_history" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
    <strong>RELISTED OPPORTUNITY</strong>
</h3>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a simple CSS like this: `<strong style="padding-left: 10px">RELISTED OPPORTUNITY</strong>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to add spacing is by using SLDS CSS classes:

```html
<h3 slot ="title" class="slds-card__header-title slds-media__body">
    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:channel_program_history" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
    <strong class="slds-m-left--x-small">RELISTED OPPORTUNITY</strong>
</h3>
```

or custom CSS classes:

```html
<h3 slot ="title" class="slds-card__header-title slds-media__body">
    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:channel_program_history" size="small" ></lightning-icon>
    <strong class="custom-class">RELISTED OPPORTUNITY</strong>
</h3>
```

```css
/* lwc.css */
.custom-class {
    margin-left: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SLDS margin class. try this

```
<h3 slot ="title" class="slds-card__header-title slds-media__body">
    <lightning-icon icon-name="standard:channel_program_history" size="small" class="slds-m-right_medium"></lightning-icon>
    <strong>RELISTED OPPORTUNITY</strong>
</h3>
```

based on the spacing required you can use slds-m-right_small or slds-m-right_large etc